# vs2010 project as service reference cannot get "enable edit and continue" to work

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, wcf, edit-and-continue

I have a three tier application in a vs2010 solution.  I want to edit the code called from the front end though the service references without having to stop code.  I can edit the front end web project without issues but when I try and edit the Logic Project or services Project it says "Changes are not allowed in the following cases..."  The only way I can get it to work is enable native debugging under the Service solution is this to be expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the issue was that I was not running the service project directly (it was just be called by the front end).  I worked out I could fix the problem by clicking right clicking the service project and selecting debug -> step into new instance.

This lead me to realise I could just set the service project to run each time by going to properties on the solution and selecting startup project and specifying both the front end site project and the services project.